# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : binding not found

Tags: r

I would like to combine several of my files into one file. I found the codes from one of the post in the website and adapted it to my own use as followed:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df2 <- list.files(pattern = "test_.*\\.csv",full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows %>% 
  transmute(Isolate=Iso,
            Condit=Condit,
            rep=rep,
            set=set,
            hpi=hpi,
            OD=OD)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : binding not found: 'Iso'
```

I don't understand why. Could somebody help me?

Thanks a lot!

The input file 1: test_.1.csv

```
    Iso rep set Condit  hpi OD
1   A22.1   1   3   T27 84  0.232
2   A22.1   2   3   T27 84  0.23
3   A22.1   3   3   T27 84  0.214
4   D2.1    1   3   T27 84  0.049
5   D2.1    2   3   T27 84  0.054
6   D2.1    3   3   T27 84  0.049
```

The input file 2: test_.2.csv

```
    Iso rep set Condit  hpi OD
1   A22.1   1   3   T27 72  0.191
2   A22.1   2   3   T27 72  0.186
3   A22.1   3   3   T27 72  0.179
4   D2.1    1   3   T27 72  0.048
5   D2.1    2   3   T27 72  0.053
```

Comment: Stating the obvious, but unless the examples you're giving are already read in, those are not CSV files despite the suffix. `read_table2` works better when copied and pasted, but SO may be reformatting tabs as spaces, so `read_table` or `read_tsv` may work on the originals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run your code and got the same error message

> Error: binding not found: 'Iso'

Reason for this seems to be `read_csv` from the `readr` package. When used to read a single file,

```
read_csv("test_.1.csv")
```

returns:

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  `Iso   rep set Condit  hpi OD` = col_character()
)
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  `Iso   rep set Condit  hpi OD`
                           <chr>
1  A22.1   1   3   T27 84  0.232
2   A22.1   2   3   T27 84  0.23
3  A22.1   3   3   T27 84  0.214
4  D2.1    1   3   T27 84  0.049
5  D2.1    2   3   T27 84  0.054
6  D2.1    3   3   T27 84  0.049
```

So, `read_csv` apparently doesn't know how to split the lines into columns.

---

The code below using `fread()` and `rbindlist()` from the `data.table` package works for me. It changes the name of the `Iso` column as requested by the OP. In addition, it adds a column indicating the origin of each row.

```
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "test_.*\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
library(data.table)
df2 <- 
  rbindlist(
    lapply(file_names, fread), idcol = "file_id"
  )[, file_id := basename(file_names)[file_id] # add origin
    ][, setnames(.SD, "Iso", "Isolate")] # rename one column

df2
#        file_id Isolate rep set Condit hpi    OD
# 1: test_.1.csv   A22.1   1   3    T27  84 0.232
# 2: test_.1.csv   A22.1   2   3    T27  84 0.230
# 3: test_.1.csv   A22.1   3   3    T27  84 0.214
# 4: test_.1.csv    D2.1   1   3    T27  84 0.049
# 5: test_.1.csv    D2.1   2   3    T27  84 0.054
# 6: test_.1.csv    D2.1   3   3    T27  84 0.049
# 7: test_.2.csv   A22.1   1   3    T27  72 0.191
# 8: test_.2.csv   A22.1   2   3    T27  72 0.186
# 9: test_.2.csv   A22.1   3   3    T27  72 0.179
#10: test_.2.csv    D2.1   1   3    T27  72 0.048
#11: test_.2.csv    D2.1   2   3    T27  72 0.053
```